# Does react native support CSS grid?

Tags: react-native

Very straight forward question, I hope you guys can help me. I was just wondering if react native support **CSS grid?** If so, how can I do it?

I know it supports flexbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing on googling around related to "Grid in React Native", "React Native grid system"??

Comment: Actually no even I didn't find anything

Answer (score 21):

As of yet, no it does not. It's currently a feature request: https://github.com/facebook/yoga/issues/867

Comment: The link is unfortunately now broken :(

Comment: Updated link (Yoga is RN's layout engine): https://github.com/facebook/yoga/issues/867